# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_user_id() WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We've been using WooCommerce subscriptions fine however it has started to cause issue when viewing orders from a users "my account" section, turning on WP_DEBUG shows the following:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_user_id() on bool in
> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/wcs-user-functions.php:381

Line 381 is:

```
if ( $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['edit_shop_subscription_status'] = true;
                }
            break;
```

Given this is an official plugin I'm not sure how an issue has developed, I also have the stack trace:

> Stack trace: #0
> /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289):
> wcs_user_has_capability(Array, Array, Array) #1
> /wp-includes/plugin.php(212):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #2
> /wp-includes/class-wp-user.php(783):
> apply_filters('user_has_cap', Array, Array, Array, Object(WP_User)) #3
> /wp-includes/capabilities.php(788):
> WP_User->has_cap('edit_shop_subsc...', 44013) #4
> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/wcs-user-functions.php(320):
> user_can(Object(WP_User), 'edit_shop_subsc...', 44013) #5
> /wp-content/plugins/tmanager/tmanager.php(76):
> wcs_get_all_user_actions_for_subscription(Object(WC_O in
> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/wcs-user-functions.php
> on line 381

The full block of code:

```
/**
 * Checks if a user has a certain capability
 *
 * @access public
 * @param array $allcaps
 * @param array $caps
 * @param array $args
 * @return array
 */
function wcs_user_has_capability( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $caps[0] ) ) {
        switch ( $caps[0] ) {
            case 'edit_shop_subscription_payment_method' :
                $user_id  = $args[1];
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $args[2] );

                if ( $subscription && $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['edit_shop_subscription_payment_method'] = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'edit_shop_subscription_status' :
                $user_id  = $args[1];
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $args[2] );

                if ( $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['edit_shop_subscription_status'] = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'edit_shop_subscription_line_items' :
                $user_id  = $args[1];
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $args[2] );

                if ( $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['edit_shop_subscription_line_items'] = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'switch_shop_subscription' :
                $user_id  = $args[1];
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $args[2] );

                if ( $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['switch_shop_subscription'] = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'subscribe_again' :
                $user_id  = $args[1];
                $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $args[2] );

                if ( $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
                    $allcaps['subscribe_again'] = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'pay_for_order' :
                $user_id = $args[1];
                $order   = wc_get_order( $args[2] );

                if ( $order && wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order, 'any' ) ) {

                    if ( $user_id === $order->get_user_id() ) {
                        $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
                    } else {
                        unset( $allcaps['pay_for_order'] );
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wcs_user_has_capability', 15, 3 );
```

Using print_r the $user_id gives a result but i cant get anything out of $subscription - could it be showing an error only for users who are NOT on a subscription plan? Any pointers greatly asppreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the guilty seems to be the `WC_Subscription` Object that return a boolean value, use instead:

```
if ( is_a( $subscription, 'WC_Subscription' ) && $user_id === $subscription->get_user_id() ) {
    $allcaps['edit_shop_subscription_status'] = true;
}
```

It should solve the issue.

Comment: that appeared to work and thus the error changed...  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Order::can_be_updated_to() in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-change-payment-gateway.php:315 - Assume this could go on and on?

Comment: @cod3t3stin Note that you are using `$args[2]` as subscription ID and as order ID in your code… So something is wrong.

Comment: As mentioned this is the official Woo Subscription plugins code, not my own but thank you.